# How to find SQLGrammarException in INSERT statement while using createNativeQuery

Tags: java, persistence

I am trying to insert to a table but the table name and values are obtained from json file while my code is running so I need to parse json and get table name, column name and data.
The Problem, I got

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
```

But I don't know where Is the problem

here is  my createNativeQuery

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + columnName + ") VALUES (" + columnValues + ")");
```

then set parameters like this

```
for (int p = 0; p < columnSpecs.size(); p++) {
 String tempColumnName = columnSpecs.get(p).getColumnName();
 if ("created_By".equalsIgnoreCase(tempColumnName)) {
  q.setParameter(p + 1, createdBy);
 } else if ("creation_Date".equalsIgnoreCase(tempColumnName)) {
  q.setParameter(p + 1, modifiedTimestamp);
 } else if ("TMP_ID".equalsIgnoreCase(tempColumnName)) {
  q.setParameter(p + 1, TMP_ID);
 } else if ("form_Id".equalsIgnoreCase(tempColumnName)) {
  q.setParameter(p + 1, formId);
 } else if ("import".equalsIgnoreCase(tempColumnName)) {
  q.setParameter(p + 1, _import);
 } else if ("key".equalsIgnoreCase(tempColumnName)) {
  q.setParameter(p + 1, key);
 } else if ("rev".equalsIgnoreCase(tempColumnName)) {
  q.setParameter(p + 1, rev);
 } else if ("revType".equalsIgnoreCase(tempColumnName)) {
  q.setParameter(p + 1, revType);
 } else if ("table_Id".equalsIgnoreCase(tempColumnName)) {
  q.setParameter(p + 1, tableId);
 } else {
  if (columnSpecs.get(p).getDataType().toLowerCase().contains("varchar")) {
   q.setParameter(p + 1, payload.getString(columnSpecs.get(p).getColumnName()));
  } else if (columnSpecs.get(p).getDataType().toLowerCase().contains("number")) {
   q.setParameter(p + 1, payload.getBigDecimal(columnSpecs.get(p).getColumnName()));
  } else if (columnSpecs.get(p).getDataType().toLowerCase().contains("timestamp")) {
   SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
   q.setParameter(p + 1, new Timestamp(format.parse(payload.getString(columnSpecs.get(p).getColumnName())).getTime()));
  } else if (columnSpecs.get(p).getDataType().toLowerCase().contains("boolean")) {
   q.setParameter(p + 1, payload.getBoolean(columnSpecs.get(p).getColumnName()));
  } else if (columnSpecs.get(p).getDataType().toLowerCase().contains("date")) {
   SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
   q.setParameter(p + 1, new Timestamp(format.parse(payload.getString(columnSpecs.get(p).getColumnName())).getTime()));
  }
 }
}
```

when I execute

```
int result = q.executeUpdate();
```

I got javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

I want to know where is my mistake but the exception doesn't say anything and Query parameter doesn't show what it is my insert query if I could see my insert string before execution but Query eather doesn't has that functionality or I couldn't find it

Comment: The easiest way would be to print your sql before executing it and trying to execute it manually on your database.

Comment: how can I print my sql, I set all the parameters via Query::setParameter() method and I couldn't find any method in Query to print it out

Comment: Start from printing "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + columnName + ") VALUES (" + columnValues + ")"

Comment: And you could always use PreparedStatements instead.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html